# Conditional Probability: Find the probability of 1 given that an odd number was obtained

Tags: probability

**Example**

Suppose that a balanced die is tossed once. Find the probability of a 1, given that an odd number was obtained.

Let's assume the events are:

> A: Observed a 1
>
> B: An odd number was obtained

I know that you can use this formula:

> P(A intersect B) / P(B)

I know the P(A) = 1/6 and the P(B) = 1/2.

But I am confused on how to find P(A intersect B). Is there a formula to find P(A intersect B)? Do I just multiply `P(A) = 1/6 * P(B) = 1/2` = (1/12)?

The books say the probablity of A intersect B is 1/6. But I do not understand how they came to that conclusion.

Comment: $A\subset B$ hence $A\cap B=A$, qed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.

Comment: Oh ok so anytime A is a subset of B then A intersection B is just A?

Comment: Indeed (these two conditions are even equivalent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set of outcomes are

$$\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

The event "an odd number is obtained" is the subset

$$B = \{1,3,5\}\subset 2^\Omega$$

Assuming your probability function is defined as

$$\mathbb{P}(\{x\}) = \frac{1}{6} \text{ for any } x \in \Omega$$

Then, we have

$$\mathbb{P}(\{1\}\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(\{1\})=\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: This kind of hides the crucial step in the middle of the last line, why not instead focus on what the OP has trouble with?

Comment: @Did What do you mean? OP doesn't understand how to find $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$. That is what I'm explaining.

Comment: Can you somehow use the fact that P(A intersect B) = P(A) * P(B given A)?

Comment: As I mentioned explicitely in my first comment, the relevant information is only in, and hidden in, the last line of your post. None of the rest is useful to understand why P(A intersect B)=P(A).